# Make index page references include part number

Tags: indexing

I have a book with three LaTeX parts. The full book is almost 1000 pages, and for a few reasons it made sense to split the physically printed thing into three individual books. (It's a textbook for a three-course sequence, and many students only take one course in the sequence.)

Now, right or wrong, I decided to reset the page numbering on each part. So part II opens on a new page 1, and so on. (It wasn't so much my decision actually. It was a requirement of the printer that the first page following the TOC have a printed page number of "1".) It worked out fine for the three separate parts although there are complications with the TOC, index, and cross-referencing across parts that I need not go into here.

Now I also want to produce one big PDF of the whole book in addition to the three smaller volumes. I'd like to leave the page numbering as it was. That is, part II will still open on page "1". So if you are reading "page 27" of part II that was printed as its own volume, it is still "page 27" of part II in the three-volume tome.

I do not mind that the TOC will start repeating page numbers, because "Part I", "Part II", and "Part III" will be clearly marked in the TOC.

My problem is the index. I have gotten myself into the position of having entries like "foo, 27" in the index. But which page 27? The one in part I, part II, or part III?

Is it possible to change how the index labels its page references? So that it might say "foo, II 27" or something like that? I am using `imakeidx` with `\makeindex[title=Index, intoc=true]`, in the preamble, and `\printindex` at the end of the book. I have looked through the `imakeidx` documentation but the most I can gather is that if this is possible, it is something more fundamental with LaTeX's indexing mechanism that I do not understand.

I'd like to avoid actually numbering all the pages to be like "II 27", but I think that is one way out of this if nothing else is possible.